# Scanner Help - Using 2 scanner methods with single getter method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm relatively new to Java taking CS1.  We've been using `Scanner`s for a few weeks and I'm more than comfortable with them in typical situations.  I've hit a spot I can't figure out though and haven't been able to get answers through research.

I have a PayRoll program I'm building for class.  We are to use the three class variables given:

- `employeeLastName`,
- `hoursWorkded`,
- `payRate`.

I made 3 individual setter methods as well as one setter that sets all three (using the scanner with all four methods).

I have no problems using the scanner to get the `employeeLastName` in its own setter, but when I do it with the method that gets the three, instead of scanning the name it just prints the prompt and skips to the `hoursWorked` input.  I don't think there are any errors with what I have typed in there.

At this point my biggest question is if it's even possible to use two different scanner/helper methods to execute a setter, or if the `nextLine()` just acts funny when used in conjunction with other scanner utilities.  Here are the important excerpts of code relating to this.  Please let me know if anything else is needed.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    private double requestDoubleFromUser( Scanner sc , String prompt )
{

    double userInput;

    System.out.print( prompt );
    userInput = sc.nextDouble();

    return userInput;

}

private String requestNameFromUser( Scanner sc , String prompt )
{

    String nameInput;

    System.out.print( prompt );
    nameInput = sc.nextLine();

    return nameInput;

        /***** Test of Employee 2 *****/

    displayEmployeeData( "\n Default Pay Period Info for Employee 2", employeePayRoll2 );
    System.out.println( "\n Please complete the employee's information to receive a period summary. " );
    employeePayRoll2.setPayRoll( requestNameFromUser( sc, "\n Employee Name: " ) ,
                                 requestDoubleFromUser( sc, "\n  Hours Worked: " ) ,
                                 requestDoubleFromUser( sc, "   Rate of Pay: " ) );
    displayEmployeeData( "\n Pay Period Data for Employee 2", employeePayRoll2 );
```

That's the part that doesn't work.  Here are the setters:

```
    public void setEmployeeLastName( String employeeLastName )
{
    this.employeeLastName = employeeLastName;
}

public void setHoursWorked( double hoursWorked )
{
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}

public void setPayRate( double payRate )
{
    this.payRate = payRate;
}

public void setPay( double hoursWorked , double payRate )
{
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this.payRate = payRate;
}

public void setPayRoll( String employeeLastName , double hoursWorked , double payRate )
{
    this.employeeLastName = employeeLastName;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this.payRate = payRate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to create methods for asking the user the input. Just create a main class with one scanner object (keep it simple) and gather all the data like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double hoursWorked, payRate;
String empLastName;

System.out.println(prompt); //enter name
empLastName = sc.nextLine();

System.out.println(prompt); //enter hrs worked
hoursWorked = sc.nextDouble();

System.out.println(prompt();//enter payRate
payRate = sc.nextDouble();
```

and then, once you have all the data, pass it to your setters:

```
    employeePayRoll2.setPayRoll(empLastName, hoursWorked, payRate);
```

Comment: Unfortunately though we have 2 classes ( 1 computational object , the other a tester ).  If I was allowed to do it that way I would but we're not supposed to.  All we are instructed to do with our main methods by our professor is to instantiate the testing object.  Since the variables are private though I wouldn't be able to change their values directly with the scanner from the other class.  Thanks though even though that won't work for this it's still a good solution in most cases.  I appreciate that aspect of it.

Comment: So in the tester, were the parameters for those methods given or did you add the scanner? I'm thinking it may be a problem when passing the scanner object. Try instantiating the scanner within each of the method's body.

Comment: yeah it was instantiated in another method.  I'll try flipping it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Nevermind that won't work if they're just local to those other methods the original won't find it and it errors out.

Comment: I should've specified earlier also (just noticed this) when I pasted it looks like the stuff under the block comment is in that method it's actually in the testing method in the testing class, not in those scanner/helper methods in the testing class.

Comment: Try adding an if statement for the requestNameFromUser method. `if(!userInput.equals(null)){`
`return userInput;`
`}else(userInput = "Scanner not working");`

Comment: Even though I didn't do it exactly the way you said you put me in the right direction which helped.